# Bootstrap variable in the HTML and script part

Tags: javascript, html

I am sending data read from a database with
`res.render('default/index', {posts: posts});`
to a handlebars template.

This code will display images correctly:

```
{{#each posts}}
    <div class="col">
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{imagefile}}">
     </div>
{{/each}}
```

Now I want to display the images in a carousel. For this I need a script in addition
to the html part.

How do I use the posts values ​​in the script?

```
<script>
.......
$('<div class="item"><img src="????????????"><div class="carousel-caption"></div>   </div>').appendTo('.carousel-inner');
......
</script>
```

Thank you in advance for a hint.

Comment: Do you actually need to do that? Instead output the elements in handlebars and only initiate the slider with the script you include in the template.

Comment: But if you do need your data from the database available to your frontend scripts, then you could either make the data globally available by outputting it as a property on the window object: `<script>window.__globalData__ = {{ yourData }}</script>` or make endpoints on your server to which you can make requests to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Emiel very much for your help.
Now I output the images in handlebars. Within the script, only the indicators are created and the active attributes are assigned.
The variable "posts" is only used to determine the number of images
for a counter. Not very elegant, but it works:

```
var j=0;

{{#each posts}} 
j++ 
{{/each}}
```

j is equal to the number of pictures.